# warning: overflow in conversion from 'long long unsigned int' to 'long int' changes value from ........ to .?

Tags: c

The above warning is giving from this line:

```
fseek(fp, -sizeof(usr), SEEK_CUR);
```

here `fp` is my file pointer and `usr` is my struct. I am doing the above for updating struct from a file..
I tried out various ways but couldn't remove warning:
more precise warnings:

```
warning: overflow in conversion from 'long long unsigned int' to 'long int' changes value from '18446744073709551304' to '-312' [-Woverflow] 
    fseek(fp, -sizeof(usr), SEEK_CUR);
```

Answer (score 5):

You get this warning because `sizeof(usr)` has type `size_t`, which is a 64-bit unsigned type on your target system (presumably Windows), negating this unsigned value `312` produces a huge value `18446744073709551304` which cannot be converted to type `long` without a loss, this out of range conversion being implementation defined anyway. You can fix this problem by writing:

```
        fseek(fp, -(long)sizeof(usr), SEEK_CUR);
```

Testing the return value of `fseek()` would help catch potential problems. Also make sure the stream is open in binary mode.

Comment: Good point about open in binary mode UV.  Also suggest that code checks the return value of `fseek()`.